# the wifi is connected in ubuntu but there is no internet access and it keeps on disconnecting

Tags: networking

```
ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3c:97:0e:28:51:ed  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:19

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1472 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1472 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:119920 (119.9 KB)  TX bytes:119920 (119.9 KB)

vmnet1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:00:01  
          inet addr:172.16.201.1  Bcast:172.16.201.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:51 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

vmnet8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:00:08  
          inet addr:172.16.109.1  Bcast:172.16.109.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:51 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c0:14:3d:c7:52:0f  
          inet6 addr: fe80::c214:3dff:fec7:520f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:28 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:2585
          TX packets:91 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1176 (1.1 KB)  TX bytes:18377 (18.3 KB)
          Interrupt:17
```

---

```
$ ifconfig wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c0:14:3d:c7:52:0f  
          inet6 addr: fe80::c214:3dff:fec7:520f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:464 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:36145
          TX packets:943 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:21922 (21.9 KB)  TX bytes:149032 (149.0 KB)
          Interrupt:17
```

---

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.220.7.253    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.220.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
172.16.109.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet8
172.16.201.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet1
```

---

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet (rev
```

---

```
$ ping -c5 google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wireless interface (wlan0) hasn't assigned any IP address (IPv4 at least). If the access point you are connecting to has DHCP server verify if you configured your interface to automatic get IP address. Other option is using static ip address in your wireless interface. If I wrong with this, maybe is a DNS problem. Try `ping 8.8.8.8` instead of `ping www.google.com`